# Laravel 8: How to add pagination after retrieving data from ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on a forum project using Laravel 8, and in this project, I have made a page for getting all the questions with specific tag. Here is the the method to do that:

```
public function tag($name)
    {
        $tag = \App\Models\Tag::findOrFail($name);
        return view('tag',[
            'single' => $tag
        ]);
    }
```

And then inside `tag.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($single->questions as $one)
  ...
@endforeach
```

But now I need to add pagination for this page, so if questions are more than a custom number, they can navigate to other pages.

In fact I had already added pagination to my other page which shows all the entire questions:

```
public function allQuestions()
    {
        $all = Question::latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('questions.allquestions',[
            'all' => $all
        ]);
    }
```

But I don't know really how to add this feature to `tag()` method.

So if you know how to add this pagination, please let me know...

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: let me guess, question has many tag and tag can be use in many question also. so there is many to many relation here?

Comment: Whops i didnt see it at your title, okay then you can just foreach the $all->tag as $tag then.

Comment: @WailanTirajoh I can rerieve data from db but now I wanted to add pagination

Comment: $all = Question::latest()->paginate(20); <<<<------ whats wrong with this?

Comment: @WailanTirajoh This was just an example, I want to add pagiantion to `tag()` method

Comment: Ah, i think i got the point. So you want to limit / paginate the tag on foreach ($all->tag) so that it doesnt show the full connected tag. is that correct?

Comment: @WailanTirajoh Yes, Exactly

Comment: Ive answer it on answer, hope it help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres ***2 choices*** for this:

***First Choice:***

```
public function tag($name)
    {
        $tag = \App\Models\Tag::findOrFail($name);
        $questions = $tag->question()->paginate(10);
        return view('tag',[
            'single' => $tag, 'questions' => $questions
        ]);
    }
```

Then, on your view, you can just loop through the questions.

```
@foreach ($questions as $question)
    ... fill this
@endforeach

{!! $questions->render() !!}
```

***Second Choice:***

```
public function tag($name)
    {
        $tag = \App\Models\Tag::findOrFail($name);
        $tag->setRelation('questions',$tag->questions()->paginate(10));
        return view('tag',[
            'single' => $tag
        ]);
    }
```

Then, on your view, you can just loop through the questions.

```
@foreach ($single->questions as $question)
    ... fill this
@endforeach
```

Comment: Method two is fine, but how to add pagination links at the blade

Comment: like first method, try {!! $single->questions->render() !!}

Comment: or {{$single->questions->links()}}

Comment: You're awesome <3